# Fields Don't show in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Fields Don't show in django admin
While trying to add role through django admin it doesn't show the field

```
class Role(Core):
    role = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.role = self.role.lower()
        super(Role, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.role.capitalize()

admin.site.register(Role)

class Core(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpNNW.png)

Comment: You should define `Core` *before* the `Role`.

Comment: furthermore the `id` is given by the database (it is the primary key) and the `created_at` and `updated_at` are items that are non-editable, so these will not show in the form either.

Comment: All your fields have `editable=False`, so as said above none  would show up...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `id` is given by the database (it is the primary key) and the `created_at` and `updated_at` are items that are non-editable, so these will not show in the form either.

This thus means that `role` would be the only field that can be used, but you specified this as [**`editable=False`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#editable), hence it will *not* show up to create/edit a `Role` object.

You should remove the `editable=False` part:

```
class Role(Core):
    #                             no editable = False ↓
    role = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.role = self.role.lower()
        super(Role, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.role.capitalize()
```